Como puedo realizar inserciones multiples en laravel?
he intentado de tantas forma y siempre me sale este error,a los input le asigno el nombre asi name="rut[]", alguien sabe como solucionar esto


Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

¡Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español! Te invito a hacer el [tour].Por favor no publiques código o mensajes de error/trazas de pila en imágenes, publica directamente el texto del código, el texto de los errores y los stack traces. Esto hace que sea menos complicado, para quien quiera ayudarte, investigar sobre el tema y hacer sus propias pruebas/adaptaciones al código, al escribir una respuesta y de esa forma aumenta tus posibilidades de encontrar la ayuda que buscas. Un saludo.

Podrías simplemente hacer la inserción directamente por cada iteración del ciclo:
public function store(CreateRequestUsuario $request)
{
    for($i = 0; i < count($request->rut); i++){
        Usuario::create([
            // Aquí pones todos los campos que deseas insertar
        ]);
    }

    return redirect()->route('ruta_deseada');
}

